# How to integrate Superset with gcloud oAuth?

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to integrate in gcloud oAuh2.0. This is the code snippet:

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
       'name': 'google',
       'whitelist': ['@gmail.com'],
       'icon': 'fa-google',
       'token_key': 'access_token', 
       'remote_app': {
            'base_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
            'request_token_params': {
              'scope': 'email profile'
            },
            'request_token_url': None,
            'access_token_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
            'authorize_url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            'consumer_key': 'myKeyID',
            'consumer_secret': 'MySecret'
        }
    }
]
```

I am able to access the authorization page and successfully sign in as well, but after the signing it redirects me to the page which shows invalid login details (Even though Google has validated it).
Here's what I receive:

[image]

What possibly could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error, I was trying to register with a pre-registered email, sorry for the confusion!